# How do I reload a block of code on a timer? VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Good afternoon.

I've got a program that requests weather from Yahoo! weather which works. However what I want to do is reload the block of code that requests the information.

It's part of a radio station - studio clock, so using a scheduled task to close & then reopen the application isn't a runner.

It only requests the information once, when the .exe file is loaded.

How do I do this with a timer perhaps? Every 15 minutes would be good.

Here's the code I've got - not my own code by the way, found online!

```
Sub GetWeatherReport(ByVal locationId As Integer)
    Me.Text = strLocations(locationId)
    Dim doc As New XPathDocument("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=" & strLocationID(locationId) & "&u=c")
    Dim nav As XPathNavigator = doc.CreateNavigator()
    Dim ns As New XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable)
    ns.AddNamespace("yweather", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0")
    Dim nodes As XPathNodeIterator = nav.[Select]("/rss/channel/item/yweather:condition", ns)
    While (nodes.MoveNext())
        Dim node As XPathNavigator = nodes.Current

        lblTemp.Text = node.GetAttribute("temp", ns.DefaultNamespace).ToString() & "°C " + node.GetAttribute("text", ns.DefaultNamespace).ToString()
        )

        weatherImage.ImageLocation = "http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/" & node.GetAttribute("code", ns.DefaultNamespace).ToString() & ".gif"

    End While
```

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of application is this: WebForms, WPF, WebForms or MVC?

Comment: Assuming this is Winforms or WPF and not an ASP.NET website, timers have a timer_Tick event.  I'd do something like using a counter that increments by one on each tickand then call your GetWeatherReport method and set the counter back to zero when counter equals some given value (15 minutes is 900 seconds, for example).  Others might suggest more elegant solutions.  This is similar to something we call a clock divider in microelectronics.

Comment: Windows form application? Sorry unsure if that's what you're looking for!

Comment: Great will try that now & report back

Comment: If you create a timer by dragging a Timer control onto your designer, it has a property called Interval; this is the number of milliseconds between ticks.  I guess in theory if you set it to 900,000 you wouldn't need the counter and the tick event would just fire once every 15 minutes.  Not sure if it has a maximum value however.